# No telnet in MacOS

Tags: osx, macports

Hi tried to use `telnet` in High Sierra, and I noticed it does not come anymore with MacOS.

I also attempted to install it via MacPorts with:

```
$ sudo port install telnet
Error: Port telnet not found
```

But it did not work. What to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After investigating a little, I found from a [ticket opened in the MacPorts bugtracker: telnet port request (High Sierra)](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/55000) about the lack of telnet, and that the needed package is `inetutils`.

So I installed `inetutils` with:

```
sudo port install inetutils
```

And know I already can use `telnet`.

PS. If Homebrew is your thing, you can also install `telnet` with:

```
brew install telnet
```

Comment: Curious... why do you choose MacPorts over HomeBrew?

Comment: already installed here, More flexibility, more ports, more stable, no ruby, it does not overwrite MacOS setups/binaries. Though reputedly HomeBrew is simpler, and MacPorts more sysadmin oriented.

Comment: HomeBrew (non-cask) doesn't overwrite MacOS binaries, either: It installs everything into /usr/local and manages it just like I do (manually) on my Debian machine. I haven't tried MacPorts, but so far I found HomeBrew quite sufficient.

Comment: @dirkt Fun fact: actually I started using MacPorts to have WireShark and dsniff...then I liked it.